# Matrices and Vectors in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, 3d

Find the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that
$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w} = \begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 7 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} \times \mathbf{w}$ for all vectors $\mathbf{w}.$

This is the image in case it's easier to understand:
[image]

All I know is that $\mathbf{A}$ is a 3 by 3 matrix. I haven't attempted it because I don't understand what this question is saying. Any advice/help?

Comment: Familiar with [Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)? $\mathbf{w}$ is a $3\times 1$ matrix and $\begin{pmatrix}4\\7\\-1\end{pmatrix}\times\mathbf{w}$ denotes the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). Does it start to make sense now?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin   I'm still a little confused though. Doesn't this just mean that A is (4,7,1) since Aw is equal to (4,7,1) * w?

Comment: K, what is a vector crossed with itself?

Comment: @WillJagy A vector crossed with itself is 0.

Comment: K, if $w$ is a (column) vector with entries $(x,y,z),$ and I give ou a fixed matrix $$ B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1&2&3 \\ 3 & 5 & 7 \\ 9 & 8 & 6 \end{array} \right) $$ then what is $Bw \; \; ? \; \;$

Comment: Bw is \begin{pmatrix}x+2y+3z\\ 3x+5y+7z\\ 9x+8y+6z\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Thank you, I actually think I figured out the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since it is given for all vectors $w$, so start with $w=e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Then you have $Ae_1=v \times e_1$, where $v$ is the vector given on the right side of the equation. This will give you the first column of $A$.

Note: $v \times e_1$ is very simple to compute if you know what cross-product means.

Comment: I think this is the answer, but I am not sure. \begin{pmatrix}0&1&7\\ \:-1&0&-4\\ \:-7&4&0\end{pmatrix}

Comment: @Krithika so, first, if that is $A,$ then what is $Aw$  when $w$ is the column vector with entries $(x,y,z) \; \; ? \; \; $   First impression, your matrix is promising, I have a vague memory that the matrix ought to be skew symmetric